# Video-Streaming (hosting) for e-learning website

Tags: video, youtube, streaming, media

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to fulfill following requirements for an e-learning platform.

- Backend in which I edit the videos, so that I can link them among themselves (like the youtube-comment function)
- The user can watch the videos only when accessing the platform (no downloading allowed!)
- videos are only accessable through user validation

My thoughts and research so far: I already found some buzzwords like Adobe Flash Media Server and names of common video-platforms. But I did'n find any service that fulfill all requirements defined, so I have to came up with my own idea(s).
I was thinking about building up a platform which uses youtube as video hoster. I can easily embed the youtube videos on my website, but I can't encrypt the "video-link", because the youtube Iframe itself contains it. I need to hide the source, so that the user can not easily figure it out.
The only solution I have at the moment: developling a custom media server (with adobe media server).

How would you "solve the problem"?

Comment: "I need to hide the source" you cannot. The client's browser needs to know the source, otherwise it cannot fetch any video data. (Yes, you could use a proxy, but that's probably too slow for video streaming.)

Comment: @WTP: thanks, you are right. You make me thinking of a streaming-server which validates the user, before streaming.
The reason for this is simple: you have to pay to watch the videos, but I do not want you to download them.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Vimp](http://www.vimp.com) will be perfect for your solution. It is a youtube like content management system. Check it out. You'll be surprised at what you'll find that's already out there instead of reinventing the wheel.